# Residual non-normality and prediction intervals

Tags: regression, residuals, assumptions, normality-assumption

Normal residuals are generally understood to be necessary for valid prediction intervals in OLS regression -- but I've never seen a definitive guidance on just how much non-normality can be tolerated, given that we never, of course, have a perfectly normal distribution. To what extent are prediction intervals robust to violations of residual normality, e.g., mild skewness (say in the vicinity of .30) or moderately excessive kurtosis (say around .50), and to what extent would the answer depend on sample size?